# Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: video/x-gst-fourcc-hev1 decoder

Tags: 14.04, codecs

While I was trying to play a video, I was getting this error

```
Required plugin could not be found

Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the
following type: video/x-gst-fourcc-hev1 decoder
```

How to fix this ? Using 14.04 and .MP4 file & default video player

Comment: what is the format of video ? mkv ?

Comment: Do you have all basic gstreamer pluggins installed ??  I use `gstreamer1.0-libav`  `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`  `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`

Comment: @SeverusTux  I haven't installed anything additional as far as I can remember. Just added " Restricted extras " while installing. Could help me with the commands required in case that will fix the issue.

Comment: Try installing the above 3 packages. It might solve the issue but i am not sure which one would. `sudo apt-get install  gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly ` .  These are the only plugins I have (no restricted-extras) and I never had a problem.

Comment: Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.